# Mini-component isn't displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component:

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";

function CreateNews(props) {
    function createList(news_) {
        news_.forEach(el => {
            const content = el.content;
            return (
                <div className="news">
                    <h3 className="heading">{ content.headline }</h3>
                    <div className="description">{ content.body }</div>
                    <div className="tags">{ content.tags }</div>
                    <a href={`http://localhost:5500/api/news/get/${el.id}`} className="toNews">ссылка</a>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
    return (
        <div className="blockOfNews">
            {createList(props.news)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateNews;
```

,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

```html
<CreateNews news={news} />
```

For some reason on a page a `blockOfNews` is empty?

[image]

Why `div.news` isn't appearing in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. The [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) doesn't return anything useful, it returns `undefined`,  so performing `return` inside of your `.forEach()` callback doesn't achieve much.
2. Even if `.forEach()` did return something your code still wouldn't work,  as your `createList` function doesn't return anything either (your currently returning to your forEach callback, not the createList function)

What you can do is use the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead of `.forEach()`. The `.map()` method takes an element `x` in your array, and transforms it to a new element `y`. This new array of transformed elements is then returned by `.map()`, which your `createList()` function can then return:

```
function createList(news_) {
  return news_.map(el => {
    const content = el.content;
    return (
      <div className="news">
        <h3 className="heading">{ content.headline }</h3>
        <div className="description">{ content.body }</div>
        <div className="tags">{ content.tags }</div>
        <a href={`http://localhost:5500/api/news/get/${el.id}`} className="toNews">ссылка</a>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```